# Python: Deque of Classes

Tags: class, python-2.7, queue, deque

I have a class, and I need to implement a queue; pushing to the left, and popping from the right (FIFO).

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a  # integer 
        self._b = b  # string

    def number(self):
        return self._a

    def name(self):
        return self._b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = X(100, "red")
    c2 = X(200, "blue")
    ...
    que = deque()
    que.appendleft(c1)
    que.appendleft(c2)
    ...
```

Also, is the best way to get the values, like so:

```
num = que[0].number()
```

Thank you in advance. If there's a better data struct for this, can you please let me know.

Edited: the second part to this question:

```
event1 = X(1, "some event")
event2 = X(2, "another event")

eventque = deque()
eventque.appendleft(event1)
eventque.appendleft(event2)
```

Is there a way to sort this eventque by the integer value? I basically need to maintain two queues. eventque must be sorted by the integer value. When I pop the event with the lowest value, I need to place it into que (this queue will be FIFO, and doesn't need to be sorted).

Edited: I figured it out. Just used a bubble sort, and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want the queue to be sorted, or to be FIFO? Those somewhat contradict each other. Python has a `deque` type built in, in the `collections` module. It also has a code that implements a priority queue (based on a binary heap built in a list) in the `heapq` module.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I made some edits. I'll look into that module, thank you.